# JS dynamic content linking

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic-content

I've managed to get my main navigation to work so that JQ loads the content HTML from another file and places them as the innerHTML of my main content div. However, each time that I refresh the page it returns me to the default state of the file, that is without the content that was dynamically altered via JQ. Also, I can't figure out a way to link to the index page with the altered content since the URL stays the same. Any idea on how to do these things?

Here's the function used for dynamically altering the content:

```
$(document).ready(function() {                                                                                                                            
  $('#menu_items').on('click', '#menu_items a', function(event) {                                                                                   
    event.preventDefault();                                                                                                                   
    var href = $(this).attr('href');                                                                                                          
    $('#main_content').load(href);                                                                                                            
  });
});
```

Comment: Why are you refreshing the page, if you are changing the content of the page with jQuery?

Comment: This is a good point. Right now I'm only doing it so that I can get back to the original version of the index, although this is only because I'm too lazy to add a link to the index, which would save a lot of time. But regardless I'd like the page content to stay as it was before the refresh, after the refresh. So that I don't get thrown back to the original version after each refresh. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Make an anchor then in the url and process it on load to load up the page you want

Comment: Is the site just straight html and javascript? If so, I think your only option is cookies.

Comment: There'll be some php in the dynamically loaded files.

Comment: @Anonymous I'm not sure I quite understand what you're getting at.

Comment: Well the PHP can store values on the server, and so can javascript cookies. But when you refresh a straight html page, nothing is saved, everything is reloaded. Your page's variables are all reset. But if the server has a value stored, it can tell the page what content to load, then when you refresh the page it will load up the content by checking that cookie, or whatever server side code you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely stole these functions from another website, http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html
but this is what you need to make this easy.

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

`$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#main_content').load($("#"+readCookie("content")).attr('href'));
  $('#menu_items').on('click', '#menu_items a', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#main_content').load(href);
    createCookie("content",$(this).attr('id'), 1);
  });
});`

just make sure all your menu links have an ID, otherwise you'll have to change this code a bit.

Comment: This seems promising. I'm too busy trying to fix the horribly formatted content I got for the site but I'll give this a try and report back when I'm done. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your problem is that you are not pushing the changes that you make on the client to the server, or storing them in any way. You have a few options:

- Create a servlet on the server that allows changes to be made to the HTML file (I would not recommend it, as any changes made on the client would carry over to all other clients).
- Use cookies: you can put a cookie whenever changes to the file are made so that you can load changes when the page is refreshed
- Use HTML 5 local storage: same concept as cookies, but newer and probably better.